# PHP counter resets

Tags: php, counter, reset

I have a problem with a PHP counter. I need to count two variables, separated with a |, but the counter often resets to `|1`. I already used the `flock` function but it still doesn't work. Moreover sometimes it doesn't increase a variable's value.

numeri.txt (the counter):

`5098|561307`

This is the PHP script:

```
$filename="numeri.txt";
$contents=file_get_contents($filename);
$fp=fopen($filename,'a');
if(!flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
{
    while(true)
    {
        usleep(100000);
        if(flock($fp,LOCK_EX))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
ftruncate($fp,0);
$contents=explode("|",$contents);
$clicks=$contents[0];
$impressions=$contents[1]+1;
fwrite($fp,$clicks."|".$impressions);
flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

How to fix the code?

Comment: It is your homework? :D

Comment: What has to do with the question?

Comment: Why are you doing a non-block in the `flock` call but then blocking the script with a while loop? Why not let the OS do the blocking?

Comment: Should I remove "LOCK_NB"?

Comment: The condition if($locked) does nothing,  $locked will always be true by this point of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output resets to "|1", then your $contents variable isn't set to anything useful.

Try writing the $contents variable each time as well so you can see what it is on the occasions that the output is "|1".

I think that $contents is the problem, but you don't show where that variable gets set originally.